# Singular Value Decomposition and Least Squares

Tags: machine-learning, linear-model, matrix, svd

From *Elements of Statistical Learning* (pp. 64, 66), they explain how the $N \times p$ data matrix $X$ can be written as $$X = UDV^{T}$$

> Here $U$ and $V$ are $N \times p$ and $p \times p$ orthogonal matrices, with the columns of $U$ spanning the column space of $X$, and the columns of $V$ spanning the row space. $D$ is a $p \times p$ diagonal matrix, which diagonal entries $d_1 \geq d_2 \geq \cdots \geq d_p \geq 0$ called the singular values of $X$.

Then they go on to say that

> $$X\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}^{\text{ls}} = X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y = UU^{T}Y$$

($\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}^{\text{ls}}$ being the least squares estimate).

What doesn't make sense to me:

1. $U$ is $N \times p$ and is orthogonal. So $U^{T} = U^{-1}$. But last I checked, only square matrices are invertible.
2. My attempt at the derivation:
   $$\begin{align}
   X\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}}^{\text{ls}} &= X(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^TY \\
   &= UDV^{T}(VD^{T}U^{T}UDV^{T})^{-1}VD^{T}U^{T}Y \\
   &= UDV^{T}[(VD^{T})(U^{T}U)(DV^{T})]^{-1}VD^{T}U^{T}Y \\
   &= UDV^{T}(DV^{T})^{-1}(U^{T}U)^{-1}(VD^{T})^{-1}VD^{T}U^{T}Y \\
   &= U(U^{T}U)^{-1}U^{T}Y
   \end{align}$$
   What did I do wrong here? [Maybe it's unreasonable to assume $U^{T}U$ is invertible, but I wouldn't know what else to do here.]

Comment: By definition of the SVD, $U^\prime U$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: @whuber Ah, so that's what "unitary" means (on Wikipedia). Thank you. Am I allowed to assume $DV^{T}$ (and $VD^{T}$ as well) are invertible? (Sorry, I am new to using the SVD.)

Comment: @whuber I suppose they might be, after giving it some thought. $D$ is a diagonal matrix, so it's invertible, and $V$ is square and orthogonal (thus invertible), so I would imagine that a product (and any transpositions involved) would be invertible as well.

Comment: Re: invertibility of the product, $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$ so if both are invertible then the product is too

Comment: $D$ is invertible if and only if $d_p$ is nonzero.  This is an implicit assumption in the second quotation.